# Text always visible over background

Tags: javascript

I have a user configurable background colour for my element which means the text over it isn't always visible. My first thoughts were to invert the foreground colour based on the background colour, but sometimes this can result in some pretty ghastly colours.

Is there an easy way I would be able to simply switch between black and white foreground colours depending on the background colour?

Comment: @Scimonster - Are you saying you can't can't read an element's background color with JavaScript? If so, that's incorrect.

Comment: @j08691 You can read it easily enough. But good luck figuring out whether white or black looks better.

Comment: You might want to consider limiting the end-user's configuration options, so instead of them picking any random background color, you provide N number of options. Each option having a nice pre-defined color combination for both background + foreground. They can still customize, but at least you know up front that the site will continue to look good.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can convert the RGB to HSL  (Hue, Saturation, Lightness) and then choose black if lightness higher than a threshold and white if its lower than a threshold.

For reference the Lightness value is calculated with:

```
L (lightness) = (M + m) / 2
```

Where M is max(R, G, B) and m is min(R, G, B).

For symmetry sake I would suggest threshold of 127.5 (half 255) but really you should play around and see if it looks good.